# Describe the skewness of the below distribution

Tags: statistics

[image]

What is the skewness of the this distribution. Is this symmetrical? Here Mean=Median but mode is not the same. But using this formula

```
 3(mean-median)/standard deviation
```

gives zero which means symmetrical. I am confused need some help to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This distribution is symmetric. This implies that the skewness is $0$. The fact that the mode (here there are actually two modes) is different from the mean and the median does not matter.

In fact there are several measures of skewness, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness#Other_measures_of_skewness . The one that I have in mind, and I think it's the most commonly used, is
$$E\left[\left(\frac{X-E(X)}{\sigma}\right)^3\right]$$
If you use this definition, the skewness is $0$ because the distribution is symmetric (you can see it from the graph, once you've centered it around $0$ by substracting the mean, the pdf is an even function).

If you use the definition 3(mean-median)/sd, you also find $0$ because mean = median.

If you use the definition (mean-mode)/sd... It's not well defined because you have two modes here.

Comment: But using this (mean-mode)/σ it is not getting zero. so how can we tell this distribution is symmetric.

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: Draw a line down the middle, and fold along it. The two halves match. That is the kind of symmetry that matters here.

Comment: @Augustin Perfect Answer. Thanks a lot.